# Laravel Carbon allow trailing data at Postgresql Timestamp

Tags: laravel, postgresql, timestamp, php-carbon

I have some timestamp records on the DB that have trailing milliseconds at the timestamp and some not have. How to allowing that trailing data (millisecond) in carbon? Is this possible?

Here's the sample of my data

[image: timestamp data sometimes have trailing millisecond]

I can't always change the data manually because there are some other services using the same database and sometimes storing timestamp with trailing milliseconds.

Comment: Please post some example timestamps

Comment: I've edit my question to add some example timestamps

Comment: only this two formats in the database or any other formats ??

Comment: yes, just this two formats in the db @Hamelraj

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `Postgres`, your timestamp probably has `TIME WITH TIMEZONE`

**Example:** `"2018-04-19 07:01:19.929554"`.

In Such case have to add a date Mutator to your Model.

**In your Model add this field for date mutator:**

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:sO';
```

## Alternate Solution:

As you have a mix of timestamps with and without milliseconds I suggest you try this solution using Laravel field mutators:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Parse the created at field which can optionally have a millisecond data.
     *
     * @param  string  $created_at
     * @return Carbon::Object
     */
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($created_at)
    {
            // Try to remove substring after last dot(.), removes milliseconds
            $temp = explode('.', $created_at);

            // If created_at had milliseconds the array count would be 2
            if(count($temp) == 2) {
                unset($temp[count($temp) - 1]); // remove the millisecond part
            } else {
                $temp = [$created_at]; // created_at didnt have milliseconds set it back to original
            }

            return Carbon::parse(implode('.', $temp))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    }
}
```

Comment: No, my timestamp type in `Postgres` is `TIME WITHOUT TIMEZONE`. It's just issue with some timestamp have a trailing millisecond, and `Carbon` seems can't deal with that

Comment: @dennbagas I've added an alternate solution to compensate for varying types of date fields

Comment: Well thats a workaround, is there another way that is more genuine?

Comment: @dennbagas consistency is assumed in a data type with specific formats (like date here). If you have mixed format dates in your database then the best solution is to fix the problem at this level. Port existing in-consistencies to a normalized format and make sure future additions to the column are the same format. Laravel user carbon and it cannot magically parse all date formats.

Answer (score 0):

> I have observed in Laravel, storing datetime in database ignores
>   millisecond field, probably depends on version and db server type.
>
> Also Laravel has whereData() and whereTime() query builders but we
>   need something like whereDateTimeTz() in all cases.

I recommend storing datetime as `unix timestamps` in database.

From user timezone convert to GMT and save it to db as millis-timestamp

```
Carbon::parse('date', 'user_timezone')->setTimezone('GMT')->getPreciseTimestamp(3);
```

While displaying just convert the db timestamp (GMT) back to user timezone including DST status.

Comment: actually i can't change the datetime format in database :(

Comment: what about adding additional column in table as updated_at_timestamps? After few months you may drop the updated_at.
You can add onCreate onUpdate event listeners to model and update new column as timestamp.

Comment: I can't add additional column to the table too. onUpdate listeners are triggered from laravel itself but the change is not from one service only, so if the other service updates the column and causing trailing milliseconds, it won't be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 7 provides better date parsing by falling back to `Carbon::parse` if the recevied timestamp from the database doesn't match the expected `$dateFormat`.

PR: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/30628